# Local notification except string in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to send local notification other than string? For instance i have Slider component for indicating download percentage. Can i show it in local notification.

```
    LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
    n.setId("download-notification");
    getId = n.getId();
    n.setAlertBody("Check notification"); //can i send Slider instead of string?
    n.setAlertTitle("Downloading");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at the moment, please file an RFE in the git project